# Renaming layer with chart pie symbology in TOC of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.3, chart

I work with ArcGIS 10.3 and when i try rename layers point1 point2 in the TOC but i can't. I using chart pie symbology:

[image]

This is the symbology tab:

[image]

Comment: What does the Symbology tab on the Properties tab for that layer look like?  I don't think it is a layer that you are wanting to rename, and reviewing the Properties may help you with your terminology.

Answer (score 1):

As you will see on the Symbology tab of the Properties for your layer, the names for the two categories being displayed on your pie charts is coming from two field names (point1 and point2).

There appears to be no label available to override these, and so if you want them to appear differently then I think your only option will be to alter the names of your fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the values in the TOC, or just in the layer properties dialog? Click on the item you want to change and press F2 or click again and it should be able to be changed there even if the option isn't available in the properties. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/renaming-a-layer.htm
I was able to do this in v9.3, so unless ESRI has a habit of removing functionality when it releases new software.... It should be do-able